# Specify custom ticks in dateplot

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

How to correctly specify ticks in date plots?

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}

%\begin{tikzpicture}
%\begin{axis}
%\addplot coordinates{
%(1, 0)
%(2, 1)
%};
%\end{axis}
%\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xtick={
2014-01-01,
2016-01-01
},
xmin=2014-01-01,
xmax=2016-07-01
]

\addplot coordinates{
(2014-01-16, 0)
(2016-01-18, 1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but it does not compile:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplots@loc@TMPc ...pgfplots@calender@ZEROSHIFT 
                                                  \relax \ifx \pgfplotstempt...
l.30 ]
```

What's very strange: If the date plot is not the first plot (e.g., uncomment the first plot in my example), everything compiles just fine.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have to specify `date ZERO` manually if you use custom xticks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
date ZERO=2014-01-01, % ADDED LINE
xtick={
2014-01-01,
2016-01-01
},
xmin=2014-01-01,
xmax=2016-07-01
]

\addplot coordinates{
(2014-01-16, 0)
(2016-01-18, 1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work. Is it intentional or a bug?

Comment: The documentation states "As of 1.13, the first encountered coordinate is used as date ZERO, i.e. it is assigned automatically without user intervention." So how I understand the documentation this is a bug.